# AFNetworking how to detect if all files were loaded

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` in my project. The main thing that I need to figure it is how can I detect moment when all my files from remote server where loaded to the Document directory on iOS device.

Right now I have this architecture:

This method has cycle and it calls download new Zip file method. Please look at the `-stopLoad` method it will invoke immediately after cycle ended. By the reasons below:

```
- (void)startLoad {
    for (NSDictionary *item in items) {

       if ([self checkIfNeedUpdateQZTestModelWithItem:item]) {
          NSString *urlString = [item objectForKey:@"url"];

          NSNumber *updateID = [item objectForKey:@"update_id"];

          [self downloadZipFileWithUrlString:urlString andUpdateID:updateID];
        }
    }
    [self stopLoad];
}

- (void)downloadZipFileWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString andUpdateID:(NSNumber *)updateId
{
    NetworkManagerBlock block = ^ {
        NSString *fileName = [self fileNameFromUrlString:urlString];
        FileManager *fileManager = [FileManager new];
        [fileManager unZipFileWithFileName:fileName andUpdateID:updateId];
    };

    [self downloadFileWithUrlString:urlString withCompletionBlock:block];
}

- (void)downloadFileWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString withCompletionBlock:(NetworkManagerBlock)block
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileName = [self fileNameFromUrlString:urlString];
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        block();

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

The reason why `-stopLoad` calls immediately is async operation as I assume. So if I need to download 10 or 20 files I don't know when last file will be downloaded. So in my case `-stopLoad` method does not tell me about complete all operations it just invokes after ending  cycle.

I suppose that I need some operation stack or something like this to figure out when all files loaded. am I right? But I am still thinking about right solution. Any ideas? Thanks.

I also have added `NSInteger` variable `operationsCount`. I decrease `operationsCount` in each `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` block and then check if variable value is equal -1 then I invoke `-stopLoad` and it works, but I don't think that is beautiful solution.

Comment: How can we look at -stopLoad if you did not include it in your code?

Comment: @Mundi stopLoad makes some thing when all files were loaded. It does not matter in my case. I just what to detect moment when all files loaded. When all files loaded we can run any method.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you have your server give some info about how much there is to download? It could be a simple API call like

```
http://yoursever.com/fileList?user=johnDoe&filter=important
```

giving you something like

```
{
 "status": "OK",
 "fileList": ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
}
```

Now you can loop through the files and call your `stopLoad` routine once it is finished.

Answer (score 1):

`stopLoad` is called *synchronously*, while all of the requests are trying to load *asynchronously*. If that method does what it sounds like it does, your requests will all be cancelled shortly after being started.

To get a handler for when a batch of request operations completes, use [`HTTPClient -enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:progressBlock:completionBlock:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests%3aprogressBlock%3acompletionBlock%3a).